# Using Swift and Objective C in the same project to get UIApplication.shared.delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, phonegap

I am trying to add the swift mailer using this: https://github.com/appcoda/Print2PDF/blob/master/Print2PDF/InvoiceComposer.swift 
to my phonegap project. 
I am only receiving one error now which is Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

There are no unused links its because I cant get the getAppDelegate from swift I need to get it from objective C i think

This is what I need to do:

```
  pdfFilename = "\(AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().getDocDir())/Invoice.pdf"
```

This is my AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@objc class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


var window: UIWindow?


class func getAppDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
    return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
}

func getDocDir() -> String {
    return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
}

}
```

but I also have a AppDelegate.m

The function func getAppDelegate breaks with error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: why two appdelegates?

Comment: I dont know how to get the UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate in objective C and push to swift

Comment: you app is originally created as swift project or objective-C project?

Comment: it is an objective C project

Comment: try using this ´((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)

Comment: The
 pdfFilename = "\(AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().getDocDir())/Invoice.pdf"
is in swift which is why not sure how to get the getAppDelegate and getDocDir in objectice C which is why created an AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Do i put that in my objective C App Delegate. how do i get the value from swift?

Comment: My native Knowlege is very poor! I am a javascript developer by day

Comment: Ok, but you have an OBjective-C project which have some parts in Swift is that what you have so far?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: then you need implement the getDocDir() method in your AppDelegate.m and add the method in the AppDelegate .h, and after that you can call that method from swift

Comment: How do i write the getAppDelegate and getDocDir in Objective C?